# Detect mobile browser with a CDN <script>

Tags: javascript, mobile, cdn, responsive

I already know this excellent answer [Detecting a mobile browser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11381730/1422096) and [detectmobilebrowsers.com](http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/).

But each time you want to use it, you have to:

1. download http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/download/javascript to get the latest updated version
2. modify it to create a function `isMobile()` that would return `true` or `false`, available anywhere in your code (no such ready-to-use function is available out-of-the-box with detectmobilebrowsers.com I think?)
3. modify it to take [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381673/detecting-a-mobile-browser#comment24518547_11381730) in consideration
4. etc.

Of course I could do it once for all, but then it wouldn't be updated often, etc.

Question: **is there a CDN version of such a mobile detection snippet (detectmobilebrowsers.js or another), with high efficiency and long time support, that would allow me to just do:**

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/detectmobilebrowsers.js?tablets=include"></script>

<script>
if (isMobile()) { ... }
</script>
```

Comment: Not sure that following 5 year old information is the best idea

Comment: @charlietfl That's precisely the goal of my question: do you know an alternative, updated, available as CDN and ready-to-use?

Comment: Look at what Modernizr can do. Other than that, my protip about detecting mobile browser: don't. Detecting mobile is lame, adapt to screen width and always offer menus that work without hover.

Comment: @JacqueGoupil: I know, but my [very specific tool](https://github.com/josephernest/bigpicture.js) isn't ready at all for mobile yet, sadly. So at least I would like to display a message "Sorry this website doesn't (work) on mobile devices yet".

Comment: @Basj Woah. Ok, cross that, your app is a pretty legit reason to check for that. Nice by the way :)